# Docker volume contents and container files not merging

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, docker-machine

The following is my docker file

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY a.txt /app
```

I have volume name my-volume which have a folder called dist. Im trying to mount my-volume to /app in the container. I use the below command.

```
docker run -v my-volume:/app -itd  -e SERVICE_ENV='test01'  8ef983161140
```

The volume is getting mounted properly, but the issue is that the a.txt file in the container is getting replaced by dist folder from volume. I want to merge the contents of volume and container in /app.

Any idea?

```
docker run -v my-volume:/app -itd  -e SERVICE_ENV='test01'  8ef983161140
```

expecting

```
/app # ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root            18 Oct 18 15:33 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            18 Oct 18 16:22 ..
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            18 Oct 18 16:22 a.txt
drwxrwxr-x    3 node     node            18 Oct 18 14:11 dist
```

Comment: The mounted content _always_ hides what is in the image; there is no "merge" operation.  This is common across all sorts of Unix mounts and isn't Docker-specific.  There is a Docker-named-volume case where it can look like a volume "passes through" to the image, but this is just a copy on the first use of an empty volume; you also tagged this with [tag:kubernetes] and this copy does _not_ happen in Kubernetes.  I'd generally avoid mounting things over directories that exist in images.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't place `a.txt` in `my-volume`, you could place `a.txt` in `/app_tmp` in the image and have a script running on startup (e.g. with `ENTRYPOINT`) that copies the file from `/app_tmp` to `/app` (that is the mounted `my-volume`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can mix contents from your container image with a volume in docker in the same folder. I believe docker will replace everything in the specified folder with the volume.

You can attach a volume to the dist folder in your app so that your dockerfile still maintains that a.txt file and you have your dist files in a volume.

```
docker run -v my-volume:/app/dist -itd  -e SERVICE_ENV='test01'  8ef983161140
```